# How do I send a Label or Button to the back?

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure on how to send a label or button to the back. If it is in front it will block the labels behind.

Comment: Have you google it? Please check the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubviewtoback?language=objc)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions are especially welcome here if they demonstrate prior effort and research, and if they show attempts at solving the problem, even though it does not work. Would you edit your question to add that information?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`sendSubview(toBack:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubview) for that, e.g.:

```
button.superview?.sendSubview(toBack: button)
```

Comment: This assumes `view` is the superview of `button`. Maybe use `button.superview?.sendSubview(toBack: button)` instead.

Comment: @vacawama: Thanks, you're right. This is more flexible.